# RewriteRules conflicting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewriterules. As you might notice, the first 6 rules are conflicting with the others.

```
RewriteRule ^(groups)/([a-z-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2&cmd=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(groups)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(events)/([a-z-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2&cmd=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(events)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2&cmd=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would like to both access:
`.com/groups/group-name` (in order to get `$_GET['ustr']`) and
`.com/groups/create` (in order to get `$_GET['cmd']`)

**EDIT:** I removed a line that wasn't supposed to be in the .htaccess.

Comment: What is the difference between cmd and ustr could you post some examples?

Comment: Hypothetical example: When visiting a news page. domain.com/news/news-title (news-title is ustr). domain.com/news/create (create is a command and works with the menusystem).

Comment: and will news title always have a dash or the dash is optional? and does cmd have any possibility of having dashes or it will be always without dashes?

Comment: Or do you have a list of commands or the list is big like more than 10 commands?

Comment: Both news-title and cmd may or may not have dashes. And the list of commands is stored in database (dynamically), so this won't help.

Comment: Then you don't have many options you will have to handle it from your code instead of having cmd and ustr you will just use 1 name and you will first verify if that is a valid command if not then a ustr or vice versa. Or you will have to change the URL to something like `/news-command/create` instead of just news

Comment: I figures something out. Please write an answer, so I can accept it for your time and your help. Thank you, have a nice day :)

Comment: Just write out what you figured and check that as an answer in this case that would be the best.